# IF Formula in Excel returning FALSE on 26.00% >= 10.01%

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel if formula - Getting 0 instead of 75
Why the given IF Formula is evaluating to FALSE? Need help with this formula

Details are in the screenshot!
[Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suvLx.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are inconsistent cell types. Try to format all values as "percentage". Maybe some values are just formatted as string, then the comparisson fails, or the values are as normal floating point values. Please not e that "10%" is just a percentage representation of the fixed value 0.1